# How to overwrite INI file

Tags: file, delphi, save, ini

I have this code which saves the location of Objects in an ini file but when I try to overwrite an already saved file, it doesn't delete the data currently in the file.

I have a popup which asks the user if they want to overwrite but it doesn't clear the whole file, how can I change it so it does?

```
procedure TForm1.SaveFile(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dialog : TSaveDialog;
begin
  Dialog := TSaveDialog.Create(self);
  try
    //dialog properties go here
    Dialog.Filter := 'Title (*.ini)|*.ini';
    Dialog.Options := Dialog.Options + [ofOverwritePrompt];
    if Dialog.Execute then
    begin
      //any saving procedures go here if required

      ShowMessage('File saved: ' + Dialog.FileName);
    end 
  else
      ShowMessage('Save file was cancelled');
  finally
    Dialog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The following procedure saves the objects to the file itself:

```
procedure TForm1.Save(const FileName: string);
var
  Ini: TMemIniFile;
  I: Integer;

procedure WhatYouAreSaving(Object: TButton);
  var
    Section: string;
  begin
    Section := 'Object'
    //Properties you want to save go here
  end;

begin
  Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(FileName);
  ////For reference, the answer provided would go here
  try
    WhatYouAreSaving(Object);
    Ini.UpdateFile;
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You don't show the relevant code.

Comment: @FreeConsulting do you need the saveseatingplan procedure?

Comment: @FreeConsulting I have added the saveseatingplan procedure

Comment: Call `Ini.Clear` after `Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(FileName);`

Comment: @LURD add this as an answer, it worked

Comment: @FreeConsulting if it was you who downvoted could you remove it pls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear the contents of the ini-file, call [Ini.Clear](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.Clear) after `Ini := TMemIniFile.Create(FileName);`

> Erases all data from the INI file in memory.
>
> Call **Clear** to erase all data from the INI file that is currently buffered in memory. All sections, keys, and values are erased.

---

To erase a section in the ini-file, use [TMemIniFile.EraseSection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.EraseSection).

Comment: And if you don't want to erase the contents of entire INI file but perhaps only part of it you might prefer using erase section instead: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IniFiles.TMemIniFile.EraseSection